# Docker Compose common YAML add service name variable

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, graylog2

I would like to send all my service logs to Graylog, but don't want to repeat my logging config.

How can I send in my service name to this YAML merge block?

```yaml
version: "3"
x-common: &common
  restart: always
  logging:
    driver: "gelf"
    options:
      gelf-address: "udp://localhost:12201"
      tag: "<service_name>"

services:
  test:
    image: debian:wheezy
    command: /bin/sh -c "while true; do date && echo "hello"; sleep 1; done"
    <<: *common
```

Comment: where does the docker docs talk about this concept?

Comment: This is a Yaml feature, I'm just using docker-compose as an example